# sinon stub not replacing function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to use sinon stub to replace a function that might take along time. But when I run the tests, the test code doesn't seem to be using the sinon stubs.

Here is the code I'm trying to test.

```
function takeTooLong() {
    return  returnSomething();
}

function returnSomething() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('ok')
        }, 1500)
    })
}

module.exports = {
  takeTooLong,
  returnSomething
}
```

and this is the test code.

```
const chai = require('chai')
chai.use(require('chai-string'))
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
const expect = chai.expect
chai.should()
const db = require('./database')
const sinon = require('sinon')
require('sinon-as-promised')

describe('Mock the DB connection', function () {

it('should use stubs for db connection for takeTooLong', function (done) {

    const stubbed = sinon.stub(db, 'returnSomething').returns(new Promise((res) => res('kk')));
    const result = db.takeTooLong()

    result.then((res) => {

        expect(res).to.equal('kk')
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(stubbed);
        stubbed.restore()
        done()
    }).catch((err) => done(err))

})
```

I get an assertion error

```
 AssertionError: expected 'ok' to equal 'kk'
      + expected - actual

  -ok
  +kk
```

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the stub being used ? The test framework in Mocha.

Comment: Can you add your `export` and `require` methods in the code that you are testing and the test code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sinon stubs the `property` of the object, not the function itself.

In your case you are exporting that function within an object.

```
module.exports = {
  takeTooLong,
  returnSomething
}
```

So in order to properly call the function from the object, you need to replace your function call with the reference to the export object like :

```
function takeTooLong() {
    return module.exports.returnSomething();
}
```

Of course based on your code, you can always refactor it :

```
var exports = module.exports = {

    takeTooLong: function() { return exports.returnSomething() }

    returnSomething: function() { /* .. */ }

}
```

Comment: is there anyway to stub function now ?

Comment: @AtulKumar Fakes might be what you're looking for? https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/fakes/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at Proxyquire to stub/spy directly exported functions. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire/