# sinon stub not replacing function.

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon

I tried a dummy module and to stub it, but does not work.

the app.js

```
function foo()
{
    return run_func()
}
function run_func()
{
    return '1'
}
exports._test = {foo: foo, run_func: run_func}
```

the test.js

```
app = require("./app.js")._test
describe('test', function(){
    it('test', function(){

        var test_stub = sinon.stub(app, 'run_func').callsFake(
          function(){
            return '0'
        })
        test_stub.restore()

        var res = app.foo()
        assert.equal('0', res)
    })
})
```

I tried the advice from:
[sinon stub not replacing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40805349/sinon-stub-not-replacing-function)

But still the same. It does not replace the function.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here. The first is that you're calling `test_stub.restore()` immediately after creating the stub, which causes it to replace itself with the original function, effectively undoing the stub completely.

`restore` is meant for cleaning up fake methods *after* your test is done. So you do want to call it, but you should do so in an `afterEach.`

Your second problem is a little more subtle. Sinon works by overwriting a reference to a function on an object, making it point at something else (in this case, the stub). It can't replace references to the same function  in other contexts.

When you call `sinon.stub(app, 'run_func')`, it's a bit like this:

```
app.run_func = sinon.stub()
```

... except that the former way stores the original value and name of `app.run_func`, allowing you to easily restore it later.

Note that at this point, the variable `app` points to the same object you exported with `exports._test = {foo: foo, run_func: run_func}` Your `foo` function, however, is not referencing `run_func` through this object. It's  referencing it directly in the scope of `app.js`, which sinon cannot affect.

Take a look at the following example. You'll also note I cleaned up a few other things:

app.js:

```
exports.foo = function() {
    return exports.run_func();
};

exports.run_func = function() {
    return '1';
};
```

test.js:

```
const app = require('./app');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('app', function() {
    describe('foo', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            sinon.stub(app, 'run_func').returns('0');
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            app.run_func.restore();
        });

        it('returns result of app.run_func', function() {
            assert.equal(app.foo(), '0');
        });
    });
});
```

Note how `exports` in `app.js` refers to the exact same object that `app` does in `test.js`. This is because modules in node export an empty object by default, which you can assign onto by way of the `exports` variable.

Comment: Thnx! I am a newbee to JavaScript, so it seems that  exports._test = {foo: foo, run_func: run_func}  creates a new object that contains copies of the original function object( I don't know if it's correct to say this way, I am from c++), I thought it references to the original object. I have to directly export the function object rather than a copy?

Comment: From a C/C++ perspective, it helps to think of every variable or object property in javascript as a pointer. You're not copying the functions to the new object so much as giving it references so you can access the functions through it.

`exports` is the object that is returned by default when you `require` the module. It is an empty object by default, and you can assign function references onto it to "export" them.

This is a pretty decent tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: Is there a way to replace the function , no matter how its called?

Comment: @Ashokkumar Unfortunately, no. This limitation is built into the way JavaScript works. Within a CommonJS module, variables at the top level of that module are local to the module, and cannot be changed from outside of the module. So you need to refer to replaceable stuff through an object that will be accessible outside of the module. The default exports object is the best candidate for that, most of the time.

Comment: Since this word is not to be found on this page yet: What we are looking here at, is indeed **a closure**, a reference (not to a literal value but a function, which as we know,  functions are normal variables. Firmly „baked in“, thus unremovable.

Comment: nb: I just worked through that eniture ES6 stubbing issue [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75311478/444255)