# How to mock esm modules functions with quibble

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Is it feasible to mock and test an esm method something like this with [quibble](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quibble)? If not do we have any other libraries for this?

Sinon was nice, but es modules cannot be stubbed with sinon. I found quibble from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50763914/3370568).

My file to test:

`module.mjs`

```js
export function getNumber() {
  return 10;
}

export function adder() {
  const a = getNumber();
  const b = getNumber();
  return a + b;
}
```

test for this file:
`module.test.mjs`

```js
import { expect } from "chai";
import quibble from "quibble";
import { adder } from "./module.js";

// passing
it("testing adder", () => {
  const result = adder();
  expect(result).to.equal(20);
});

// failing
it("mocked test", async () => {
  await quibble.esm("./module.js", {
    getNumber: () => 30,
  });
  const result = adder();
  expect(result).to.equal(60); // still returns 20
});
```

```sh
$ mocha --loader=quibble "**/*/module.test.js"
```

```sh
  ✔ testing adder
  1) mocked test

  1 passing (9ms)
  1 failing

  1) mocked test:

      AssertionError: expected 20 to equal 60
      + expected - actual

      -20
      +60
```

Comment: Generally, quibble wasn't designed to be used independently from testdouble.js, so if you're new to the library or if you're not comfortable with figuring out its internals, I'd recommend using [testdouble](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js) and looking at its top-level `td.replaceEsm` function for this

Comment: I think the `adder`-function you test needs to be reloaded. Hence, I would try to reload the `./module.js` inside the `it`-test-function after the `esm.quibble...` via `const mod = await import('./module.js')`. Then test with `const result = mod.adder()`