# TypeError: ES Modules cannot be stubbed - Sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js, sinon

Stubbing with Sinon returning an error for *named* function exports and it's working as expected for *default* function exports.

In the code below, `foo1Stub = Sinon.stub(foos1, "foo1");` causing an error `TypeError: ES Modules cannot be stubbed` when run tests using command `npm test`

**package.json**

```
    {
      ....
      ....
      "scripts": {
         "test": "npx mocha --exit --timeout 0 'tests/**/*.test.js'",
      },
      "type": "module",
      ....
      ....
    }
```

**foo1.ts** (named function export)

```
    export async function foo1() {
      return {};
    }
```

**foo2.ts** (default function export)

```
    async function foo2() {
      return {};
    }
    export default { foo2 }
```

**bar.ts**

```
    import * as foos1 from './foo1.ts';
    import {default as foos2} from './foo2.ts';

    async function bar() {
        const result1 = await foos1.foo1();
        const result2 = await foos2.foo2();
        return {result1, resutl2};
    }
```

**bar.test.ts**

```
    import * as foos1 from './foo1.ts';
    import {default as foos2} from './foo2.ts';
    import {default as bars} from './bar.ts';

    describe("bar tests", function() {
       const foo1Stub, foo2Stub;

       this.afterEach(() => {
           foo1Stub.restore();
           foo2Stub.restore();
       });

      it("should success", async function () {
         foo2Stub = Sinon.stub(foos2, "foo2");
         foo1Stub = Sinon.stub(foos1, "foo1"); // TypeError: ES Modules cannot be stubbed 

        await bars.bar();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like there's some important information missing here. Could you include your entire `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763323/stub-an-export-from-a-native-es-module-without-babel - have you checked the answers there?