# Sinon stub not properly replacing stubbed function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, chai

I have a function with depends on another function and instead of testing the dependency I just want to test specific results of that dependency function. However, when I stub the function nothing happens and the return result is as if I never stubbed the function in the first place.

Example code:

```
// File being tested
function a() {
  let str = 'test';
  return b(str);
}

function b(str) {
  return str + str;
}

module.exports = {
  a: a,
  b: b
};

// Test file
let test = require('file.to.test.js');

it('should correctly stub the b function', () => {
  sinon.stub(test, 'b').returns('asdf');
  let result = test.a();

  // Expected 
  assert(result === 'asdf');

  // Received
  assert(result === 'testtest');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stub have no expected effect because you've stubbed property of imported object. However, `function a()` keeps calling the original `function b()`, because it calls function, not an object method.

If you change the code the way that there is an object with property `b` and `a`, and property `a`, calls property `b`, then it would work the expected way:

```
const x = {};
x.a = () => {
  let str = 'test';
  return x.b(str);
}

x.b = (str) => {
  return str + str;
}

module.exports = x;
```

Also, have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931815/sinon-stub-not-replacing-function), it describes similar problem.

Comment: Please clarify, what if there was only single-function 'a' ?

Comment: @MuhammadUzair it'll be totally different story, so feel free to post your question if you have something to ask